# What software or programs can I use wherein I can record keystrokes

Tags: keyboard, windows-10, macros, typing, keystrokes

What software or programs can I use wherein I can record keystrokes?

I will use this in filling out forms on the web, and I want to record several keystrokes, ie (like the examples below):

tab

tab

Invoice 21

tab

Purchase 4

tab

For Printing

tab

enter

I saw certain softwares (AutoHotKey and another one), but those are too complicated for me. I dont know how to code, etc. Are there any other ready-made alternative, wherein I will just record what needs to be typed (keystrokes), then run it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at **iMacros**. It's a browser addon that allows you to run mechanic tasks automatically, even if they involve using the mouse.

You **don't need any programming skills**, but it supports easy scripting for cool things like loops and conditionals (just in case you want to do more complex stuff).

- [iMacros for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp)
- [iMacros for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/)

If you need to use macros outside the web browser (like in other programs, for example notepad), there are other installable alteratives such as **[Mouse Recorder](http://www.mouserecorder.com/)**.

Comment: Is there an installed version of this, or are there any other software which I can installed in my laptop, so I can also use it in other applications (ie: notepad, wordpad, etc)?

Comment: I've edited the answer to cover that cases, too.